# Win7 regedit falsely reports successful merge

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, text-editors

I'm trying to hijack notepad with the hack described at http://www.flos-freeware.ch/doc/notepad2-Replacement.html.

I created a registry file to do this, but it won't work. The confusing thing is that regedit reports a successful merge. It did indeed create the key, but it will not create the value (Win7 ultimate 32-bit).

Here's the relevant code:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe]
"Debugger"="\"C:\\Program Files\\_doc-related\\AkelPad\\AkelPad.exe" /z"
```

I've also fiddled around with the quotation marks (reducing them to one set and taking away the double backslashes, etc.), like so...

```
"Debugger"="C:\Program Files\_doc-related\AkelPad\AkelPad.exe" /z
```

...and still get the same result. Anybody know what's going on? Of course I could just do this manually in regedit (at least I assume so--haven't tried, stubbornly holding out for a working regfile), but I want to find out what's going on because I need to know whether there are some "protected" items that simply can't be done by regfile. Although I would expect such keys to report that they can't be changed, as do other system-protected keys, rather than generating the kind of false positive I'm getting.

Comment: If you want a working REG file or want to see what mistake you're making, the easiest way is to open regedit, add the value, export to a REG file and compare with your non-working version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on for you trying to merge, but you can try the `reg` command instead:

- Open a command-line as Administrator.
- Type/paste:

  reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe" /v Debugger /t REG_SZ /d "\"C:\Program Files_doc-related\AkelPad\AkelPad.exe\" /z"
- Hit Enter. :)

[image]